# Stanford NLP: how to disable warnings?

Tags: warnings, suppress-warnings

Stanford NLP pipeline issues lots of warnings particularly disturbing in production setup:

```
WARN  Untokenizable: � (U+FFFD, decimal: 65533)
```

Is there a way to disable them?

Answer (score 2):

If you are working directly with a Tokenizer, the answer Denis Kulagin gives is good; if you are operating at the higher level of a StanfordCoreNLP pipeline, you can simply give the property (or equivalent command-line option):

```
tokenize.options = untokenizable=noneDelete
```

(to silently delete all unknown characters) or to silently keep them:

```
tokenize.options = untokenizable=noneKeep
```

Answer (score 0):

One can do it that way:

```
Reader reader = new StringReader(paragraphText);
DocumentPreprocessor documentPreprocessor = new DocumentPreprocessor(reader, DocumentPreprocessor.DocType.Plain);

TokenizerFactory<? extends HasWord> factory = PTBTokenizer.factory();
factory.setOptions("untokenizable=noneDelete");
documentPreprocessor.setTokenizerFactory(factory);
```

From here: https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/issues/103#issuecomment-157793500